# Running tests in chrome but just getting data;. in every browser window

Tags: ruby, capybara, rspec

My test suite (ruby, rspec, capybara) was able to run browser based feature tests before but they somehow are broken now, and none pass.  This only happens on my Ubuntu machine.  On other machines they are still passing ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a bug in chromedriver.
Updating to a more recent version solves this.

Specifically this was fixed in chromedriver version

> 2.24

at least for Ubuntu. A couple of other of our feature specs had issues with this fix which I am addressing separately.  Looks chromedriver is the moving piece where the fixes happen right now.